# Unable To Make Front Control Transparent Over PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, transparency, picturebox

I am trying to place a custom user control over the top of a PictureBox control but I cannot seem for the life of me how to set the transparency of the user control so it doesn't chop out the PictureBox image.

My User Control consists of a RectangleShape with text in the middle to create a 'Badge' icon on top of an image (see pictures below).  The PictureBox and User Control both sit inside a Panel control and I have set the `PictureBox.SendToBack()` property and `UserControl.BringToFront()` property.

What I am left with is this:

[image]
[image]

My Code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks

Public Class BadgeIcon
    Inherits UserControl

    Private _value As Integer
    Private canvas As New ShapeContainer
    Private Badge_Icon As New RectangleShape
    Private rect As New Rectangle
    Private m_BorderColor As Color = Color.White
    Private m_FillColor As Color = Color.Red
    Private m_BorderThickness As Integer = 2
    Private m_BadgeFont As New Font("Segoe UI", 7, FontStyle.Bold)
    Private m_BadgeText As String
    Private m_TextColor As New SolidBrush(Color.White)
    Private m_TextSize As Size
    Private m_TextPadding As Integer = 5

    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _value = value
            m_BadgeText = CStr(_value)
            m_TextSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(m_BadgeText, m_BadgeFont)
            rect.Width = m_TextSize.Width + m_TextPadding
            rect.Height = m_TextSize.Height + m_TextPadding
            Me.Refresh()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = &H20
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property


    Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, False)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
        UpdateStyles()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        canvas.Parent = Me
        Badge_Icon.Parent = canvas
        canvas.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)

        'Create Badge Icon
        With Badge_Icon
            .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
            .BorderColor = m_BorderColor
            .BorderWidth = m_BorderThickness
            .BorderStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid
            .CornerRadius = 11
            .FillColor = m_FillColor
            .FillStyle = FillStyle.Solid
            .SelectionColor = Color.Transparent
        End With

        AddHandler Badge_Icon.Paint, AddressOf BadgeIcon_Paint
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        DrawBadgeIcon(e)
    End Sub

    Public Sub DrawBadgeIcon(e As PaintEventArgs)
        Try
            'Alter the size of the icon to fix the text
            With Badge_Icon
                .Location = New Point(rect.Left + 1, rect.Top + 1)
                .Size = New Size(rect.Width, rect.Height - 1)
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorTrap(ex, "cls_NotificationBadgeIcon: DrawBadgeIcon()")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BadgeIcon_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        Dim textRect As New Rectangle(2, 2, m_TextSize.Width + m_TextPadding - 1, m_TextSize.Height + m_TextPadding - 2)

        'Draw the Text
        Dim flags As New StringFormat
        flags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        flags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
        e.Graphics.DrawString(m_BadgeText, m_BadgeFont, m_TextColor, textRect, flags)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then to add everything to my main form I call the following:

```
Dim pic As New PictureBox
        pic.Image = My.Resources.Notifications
        pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        pic.Location = New Point(21, 221)
        pic.Size = New Size(42, 29)
        pnlLeftMenuBar.Controls.Add(pic)
        pic.SendToBack()

Dim Counter_Notify As New BadgeIcon
Counter_Notify.Location = New Point(50, 240)
        pnlLeftMenuBar.Controls.Add(Counter_Notify)
        Counter_Notify.BringToFront()
```

And simply use `Counter_Notify.Value = 1` to update the counter value.

How can I remove the square rectangle chopping out the background image?  Or should I be setting this up an entirely different way?  I'm a little new to User Controls.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: a transparent background doesnt mean what you think it does.  For a Transparent BG, Net/Windows uses the parent backcolor.  Since the parent of your UC is the panel, thats what will paint. You can see it change as you drag a Label around on a form with different things on it.  Instead of stacking controls, you could draw the badge/overlay onto the image you want to modify.

Comment: @Plutonix Ah okay... I did play around with painting the image directly into the panel which did give me the results I required, however, I then couldn't attach any event handlers to the image (e.g. Tooltip and Click events), so I went with a picturebox.  So is there anyway around this issue then?

Comment: draw the overlay onto the image, post the image to the panel or picbox and use the control's events for clicks

Comment: @Plutonix So are you suggesting not using a user control at all?  Just create a PictureBox control, add the image and then draw the RectangleShape on top?

Comment: It worked, you are seeing the panel's background.  Because you added it to the panel, add it to *pic* instead.  No special code required either, just set the BackColor to Color.Transparent.  And yes, just drawing it in an event handler for the pic.Paint event is much more efficient.

Comment: Okay, I seem to be experiencing some issues trying to add a RectangleShape control into a PictureBox...  I have tried to use `.Parent =` and `.Container =` but both give me an error.

Comment: How about using `GDI+` to draw on top of the image?

Comment: The reason I chose to use a ShapeControl (or RectangleShape) is because I couldn't work out how to draw a rounded rectangle without having lines through it where arcs met lines, etc.  It gave a really ugly appearance, so I chose to use a shape control to give me a more neater approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the paint event you can draw right on the picturebox itself.

```
Private Sub pb__Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles pb.Paint
 Dim bgRect As New Rectangle({x,y,width,height})
 Dim textRect As New Rectangle(bgRect.X - {?}, bgRect.Y = {?}, width, height)
 e.Graphics.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), bgRect)
 e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.White, 10), bgRect)
 Using sf As New StringFormat
  sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
  sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
 e.Graphics.DrawString("1", {your font}, {your brush}, textRect, sf)
 End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Just working through your example and looks like this could work well.  Is there anyway I can change the ellipse to a rounded rectangle though as the more text put into the badge, the more it starts to look like an oval (which is what I was trying to avoid)?

Comment: The shape of the ellipse is dependent on the height and width, if they are equal it will be round and not oval

Comment: Sorry yes I do understand that, however, I am only wanting the ellipse to grow width ways, not in height.  I have adjusted your example to grow the width of the ellipse based on the width of the text, but I get an oval shape once it hits 3 digits.

Comment: You can make a second rectangle for the text to grow and not the Ellipse and the Stringformat with apply to that rectangle

Comment: Thankyou to everyone for they're help and comments. I now have exactly what I was trying to achieve!